# A function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

Tags: 7-segment

I'm trying to light up 81 on a 4-digit 7-segment display, but when I try to upload the code to my Uno R3 it gives me this error: "a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token". I'm new to Arduino and this is my second day using it, so I would like to get help and know how to fix this problem. Here is my code:

```
int isej1 = 2;
int isej2 = 3;
int vienetas[] = { 12, 11 };
int astuonetas[] = { 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7 };

void setup() {
  pinMode (vienetas[2], OUTPUT);
  pinMode (astuonetas[8], OUTPUT);
  pinMode (isej1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (isej2, OUTPUT);
}

void uz_vien() {
  digitalWrite (vienetas[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite (vienetas[1], HIGH);
}

void uz_astuon() {
  digitalWrite (astuonetas[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite (astuonetas[1], HIGH);
  digitalWrite (astuonetas[2], HIGH);
  digitalWrite (astuonetas[3], HIGH);
  digitalWrite (astuonetas[4], HIGH);
  digitalWrite (astuonetas[5], HIGH);
  digitalWrite (astuonetas[6], HIGH);
}

void is_vien() {
  digitalWrite (vienetas[0], LOW);
  digitalWrite (vienetas[1], LOW);
}

void is_astuon() {
  digitalWrite (astuonetas[0], LOW);
  digitalWrite (astuonetas[1], LOW);
  digitalWrite (astuonetas[2], LOW);
  digitalWrite (astuonetas[3], LOW);
  digitalWrite (astuonetas[4], LOW);
  digitalWrite (astuonetas[5], LOW);
  digitalWrite (astuonetas[6], LOW);

void loop() {
  digitalWrite (isej1, LOW);
  digitalWrite (isej2, HIGH);
  void uz_vien();
  delay(5);
  void is_vien();
  digitalWrite (isej1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (isej2, LOW);
  void uz_astuon();
  delay(5);
  void is_astuon();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a "}" just before `loop`

```
  void is_astuon() {
    digitalWrite (astuonetas[0], LOW);
    digitalWrite (astuonetas[1], LOW);
    digitalWrite (astuonetas[2], LOW);
    digitalWrite (astuonetas[3], LOW);
    digitalWrite (astuonetas[4], LOW);
    digitalWrite (astuonetas[5], LOW);
    digitalWrite (astuonetas[6], LOW);
   } // <- missing here.
  void loop() {
```

Answer (score 2):

The importance of proper indentation is clear here...

I thought you were missing a closing curly braces. When you type code, press regularly cmd/ctrl-T to ident your code -- it helps catching mistakes. You are indeed missing one, for `is_astuon()`.

Moreover these lines are wrong too:

```
**void** uz_vien();
delay(5);
**void** is_vien();
digitalWrite (isej1, HIGH);
digitalWrite (isej2, LOW);
**void** uz_astuon();
```

The `void` part is not needed and creates the error.